# ForbiddenAttributesError error for collection_select with has_many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form, in which i have to select profile, then a sub category and then the product name as below.

```
<div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInRight">

    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2">
        <h2>Create New Product</h2>
        <%= form_for @product, url: {action: "create"} do |f| %>
        <% @product.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
             <p class="alert alert-danger"><%= msg %></p>
        <% end %>

        <%= f.label :profiles, "Profile" %>

        <%= f.collection_select(:profiles, Profile.all, :id, :name, {include_blank: '- Please Select -'}, {:class=>'form-control',:required => true, :title => 'Please Select Profile or Create a new Profile'})%>

        <%= f.label :sub_categories, "Sub Category" %>
        <%= f.collection_select(:sub_categories, SubCategory.all, :id, :name, {include_blank: '- Please Select -'}, {:class=>'form-control',:required => true, :title => 'Please Select Profile or Create a new Profile'})%>

        <%= f.text_field :name, :class=>"form-control", :placeholder => "Product Name", :required => "true" %>

        <%= f.submit "Create", :class=>"btn btn-primary" ,:title => "New Product", "data-confirm" => "Do you really want to create?"%>
        <% end %>
    </div>  
</div>
```

it sends the params as follows

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"aQN2cZCOMdesKEJmZN3Ddw7woPtZTIWrgoph+LOkGoA=",
 "product"=>{"profiles"=>"1",
 "sub_categories"=>"3",
 "name"=>"Gel"},
 "commit"=>"Create"}
```

Hence I have declared the strong parameters in product controllers as follows:

```
def products_params
    params.require(:product).permit(:id, :name, :profiles, :sub_categories)
  end
```

Product model

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :profile_products
    has_many :profiles , through: :profile_products

    has_many :profile_products
    has_many :sub_categories , through: :profile_products

end
```

Profile model

```
 class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_many :profile_products
        has_many :products , through: :profile_products

    end
```

Sub Category Model

```
class SubCategory < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :profile_products
    has_many :profiles , through: :profile_products

    has_many :profile_products
    has_many :products , through: :profile_products

end
```

ProfileProduct model

```
class ProfileProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :sub_category
end
```

I know the error is with strong parameters, but I am confused on how to handle it. can some1 point me in the right direction.

Error

```
activemodel (4.1.8) lib/active_model/forbidden_attributes_protection.rb:21:in `sanitize_for_mass_assignment'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:24:in `assign_attributes'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/core.rb:453:in `init_attributes'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/core.rb:196:in `initialize'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:30:in `new'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:30:in `new'
cancancan (1.9.2) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:85:in `build_resource'
cancancan (1.9.2) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:66:in `load_resource_instance'
cancancan (1.9.2) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:32:in `load_resource'
cancancan (1.9.2) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:25:in `load_and_authorize_resource'
cancancan (1.9.2) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:10:in `block in add_before_filter'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:440:in `instance_exec'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:440:in `block in make_lambda'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:160:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:160:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:232:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:73:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:678:in `call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:84:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
/Users/arunbhat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/Users/arunbhat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/Users/arunbhat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread
```

Comment: Please paste the error log ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 #app/db/migrate/20150116071437_create_products.rb
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :brand

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
 #app/db/migrate/20150116071503_create_profiles.rb
class CreateProfiles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :profiles do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end


 #app/db/migrate/20150116071631_create_products_profiles.rb
class CreateProductsProfiles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :products_profiles, id: false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :product, index: true
      t.belongs_to :profile, index: true
    end
  end
end


#product.rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :profiles
end

 #profile.rb
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products
end


#app/controllers/products_controller.rb
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @product = Product.new
  end

  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)

    #select your profile based on chosen params.
    selected_profile = Profile.where(id: params["profiles"]).first

    #now, assign them to the product.
    @product.profiles  << selected_profile
    if @product.save
      redirect_to products_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private
  def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit(:name, :brand)
  end
end


 #app/views/products/_form.html.erb 
  <%= form_for(@product) do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :brand %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :brand %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :profile, 'Select a profile' %> 
    <%= select_tag(:profiles, 
    options_from_collection_for_select(Profile.all, :id, :name) ) %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

This shows the associations,model,controller & view code.(of product & Profile relationship)! Similarly try to construct the product <-> subcategory(many to many association)

Check this [doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association), this will help you :)

Comment: So then how do i link the products with profile and sub category if i remove it?

Comment: As per your defined association:  a product can have many product_profiles, that means your product_profile model should hold attribute product_id. (Note: you are doing the reverse). 

Example: School(:id, :school_name, :location) has many students, then students table should hold(:id, student_name, :age, :school_id) ! Are you getting me ?

Comment: First you need to fix it up on the associations(depending on how you want the relationship to be/based on your business logic).
You should take a look at this basic has_many association example : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/images/has_many.png

Then take a look at following document & establish your has_many :through association properly :)
http://www.xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/3.2/ar-many_to_many.html
Hope you find those useful :)

Comment: Thanks for the help, my product_profile table has the attribute product_id, profile_id and sub_category_id. What I believe is I am handling the posted parameters wrong way. its related to strong parameters.

Comment: Are you creating the product now or product_profile ? from params list it looks like product ? please clarify.

Comment: Yes I am creating a product, product_profile is internediate table for many to many relationship

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68935/discussion-between-ajay-and-arun).

Comment: Will you please join me in the stack chat, that might help :)

Answer (score 0):

I would go the route of nested attributes. Your form would change to

```
f.fields_for(:profiles) do |profile_form|
  profile_form.collection_select(:id, Profile.all ...)
end
```

And your controller would change to `params.permit(:profiles_attributes)`
and your `Product` model would need `accepts_nested_attributes_for :profiles`

Alternatively you could just define an accessor on the `Product` model to capture it in the view and save it manually:

`attr_accessor :profile_id`

Comment: Yes, i tried the nested form, but the collection is not being displayed :(